# Create decision tree as aggregate function without nesting RDD

Tags: apache-spark, decision-tree, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I have a big set of rows that contain a not unique ID and a vector of features. I need to aggregate all the features for each ID and generate decision trees for each one using all those features.

I've tried all sort of workarounds using RDD or dataframes but I always end up in a dead end. As long as I know, nesting RDD is not allowed, so I can't get the necessary RDD[LabeledPoint] to train the trees inside a map function.

Having a structure like

```
idFeatures: RDD[(String, Iterable[LabeledPoint])]
```

What I would like to do is something similar to this (which returns a NullPointerException because of the nesting RDD):

```
  val trees = idFeatures.groupByKey().mapValues(features => {
     DecisionTree.trainRegressor(sc.parallelize(features.to[Seq]),  Map[Int, Int](), impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)
  });
```

Is there a way to do it without iterating all over the set of distinct id and generate the trees one by one (not a choice given the size of the id set)?

Comment: How much data you have? How many different ids and points per id? W

Comment: I have around 40 million id with a number of points between 1 and 500 per id. Having in mind that there are not many of them, I was thinking about implementing the tree construction myself, but I would rather use the ones that mlib provide

Answer (score 0):

Look  into using the RDD.**treeAggregate**

```
def treeAggregate[U: ClassTag](zeroValue: U)(
      seqOp: (U, T) => U,
      combOp: (U, U) => U
```

You can put the trainRegressor in the Sequential Op (first parameter) and then the rollup actions in the Combine Op (second parameter)

Comment: I 'm not sure I understand this answer. I thought about something similar but still have a problem with nested RDD. The trainRegressor function requires the full partition as an RDD of labeled points for each call, so I can't use it as a sequential operation (unless I implement a trainRegressor function that ads each feature individually to the tree).